# CloudFormation Template for ElasticTranscoder

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, aws-cloudformation

As part of infra automation we are using cloudformation for automating the AWS infrastructure. We are utilising the service ElaticTranscoder as well, as i understand cloudformation yet does not provide support for ElasticTranscoder, is there any efficient way to automate ElasticTranscoder using cloudformation.

Answer (score 1):

Custom resources provide a way for you to write custom provisioning logic in AWS CloudFormation template and have AWS CloudFormation run it during a stack operation, such as when you create, update or delete a stack.

Check out [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cfn-customresource.html#w2ab1c21c10d192c17) example.

Also, a quick google search gives me [this result](https://github.com/mazerte/aws-cloudformation-elastic-transcoder-pipeline).

Comment: Thank you bhalothia. Yes i did get the same result when do a google search but i was looking for something easy way to automate it like some kind of template so that i can incorporate that in my existing template

Answer (score 0):

Another option is not using CloudFormation. You can use Terraform which does support Elastic Transcoder.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/elastic_transcoder_pipeline.html

Ansible also has third-party support for it.

https://github.com/wimnat/ansible-modules/blob/master/elastictranscoder/elastictranscoder.py

Last but not least, you can vote for this feature in AWS wish list by liking or retweeting the request.

https://twitter.com/search?q=%23awswishlist%20transcoder&src=typd
https://awswishlist.com/